# Why does split gives extra empty string while splitting in python?

Tags: python-2.7, split

Using examples to demonstrate my doubt

```
example = "$2000"  
example.split("$")  
['', '2000']
```

but if i do

```
example2 = "2000$3000"
example2.split("$")
['2000', '3000']
```

why there is not extra empty string in this example ?
how split is working behind the scene ?

Comment: It's not relevant to your question, but it's hard to believe your first example.  Shouldn't you be getting `['', '2000']`, not `['', ' 2000']`?  Please always copy and paste transcripts exactly.

Comment: I think it makes sense that when you `split` a string containing a single delimiter, you get two pieces.

Comment: You should accept the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Because you split on a *separator.* If you split the string `$2000` with the `$` separator, there is an empty string on the left and `2000` on the right:

```
            $2000
nothing____/ \____2000
```

With the second case of `2000$3000`, there is still only *one* separator so it still produces *two* values in the array. It's just that the value left of the separator is `2000` rather than an empty string:

```
     2000$3000
2000____/ \____3000
```

Provided you don't limit the `split` by specifying the maximum number of splits allowed, the resulting array size should always be one more than the number of separators.

If you want to remove *all* empty strings from the resultant collection, you can do it with list comprehension, the third segment below:

```
>>> s = '$$$1000$$2000$3000$$$'           # test data

>>> [x for x in s.split('$') if x != '']  # remove all empty strings
['1000', '2000', '3000']
```

There are other ways to get rid of blanks at just the ends as well, either one or all:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='$$$1000$$2000$3000$$$'

>>> re.sub('^\$|\$$','',s).split('$')         # just one
['', '', '1000', '', '2000', '3000', '', '']

>>> re.sub('^\$*|\$*$','',s).split('$')       # all at the ends
['1000', '', '2000', '3000']
```

Comment: What about this `re.sub(r'\$+', " ", s).split()`

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

`It (the argument to the function) specifies a string to be used as the word separator. The returned list will then have one more item than the number of non-overlapping occurrences of the separator in the string.`

The number of occurrences of the separator in your example is 1.
Therefore `split` will return 2 elements.  The 1st element must be the empty string since there's nothing before the separator.

Your second example doesn't have an empty string in the returned result because `2000` came before the separator `$`.

You can think of the `split` function as slicing a string into array elements wherever the separator occurs.